# "error_message": "'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'",

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, tastypie

i am new python so using post method 
with my data

```
{
"name":"test nassssme123",
"email_id":"test123@gmail.com",
"subject":"test Subject",
"message":"test Message",
"date":"2222222212"
}
```

on that time is giving me error

```
{
    "error_message": "'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'",
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 201, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 432, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 464, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1340, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2104, in obj_create\n    return self.save(bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2251, in save\n    bundle.objects_saved.add(self.create_identifier(bundle.obj))\n\n  File \"/home/rahul/pyworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2232, in create_identifier\n    return u\"%s.%s.%s\" % (obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name, obj.pk)\n\nAttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'\n"
}
```

and get method is working fine for me

my package are

```
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.8
django-extensions==1.5.2
django-tastypie==0.12.1
ipython==3.1.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
six==1.9.0
```

Comment: i am not getting this point

Comment: Ok, sorry, from the tags I guess it is a post request to an API endpoint provided by `tastypie`? How do you test the `POST` request, do you have a form that you submit or maybe use another tool? (something like `curl` or `postman`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about versions Django **1.8** and Tastypie don't work properly together right now. At least can't be installed the way we did before with pip.
If you want to get them work install merged tastypie code supporting Django 1.8 this way:

```
pip install -e https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie#egg=TastyPie
```

and update your requirements.txt. Delete **django-tastypie==0.12.1** and run:

```
pip freeze> requirements.txt
```